# Disadvantanges of post in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am facing a general problem...i have experienced that post in ajax some time do not work properly...here is my code which i am using from years...some time it works and some time do not work for the same code....

```
$(function() {
var response = '179793678ActualWinter.jpg';
var rand_key = '77983890233423';
var id = 1;
    $("#btn").click(function () {
    $.post("ajax_files/test.php", { name: response, rand_key: rand_key,rentals_id:id }, function(data) {
        alert(data);

        });
    });
});
```

alert is empty even if i echo "HI"; on test.php...what can be the reason?Is this related to Browser?or this method is oblique in new updated jquery?

Comment: `live()` is deprecated and removed from the latest jquery version.

Comment: i updated code...btn event is firing,

Comment: You should use the Network tab in your browser's console to debug your Ajax Requests, it shows all the HTTP requests. You will see whether it's a mistyped URL, server problem, etc. One thing is quite sure: the problem is in your code/setup, not in the `.post()` method...

Comment: window.console && console.log(data); try this instead of an alert and check the console if its empty or some kind of object which alert isnt able to display

Answer (score 1):

`live()` is deprecated and removed from the latest jquery version.

Perhaps the ajax call isn't always successfull. If you are using jquery 1.5 or above, you could check for errors using:

```
$.post("ajax_files/test.php", { name: response, 
                                rand_key: rand_key,
                                rentals_id:id },
function(data) {
         alert(data);
}).fail(function(jqXhr){
     alert(jqXhr.responseText);
});
```

For older versions:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_files/test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(){ },
    error: function(jqXhr){  
        alert(jqXhr.responseText);
    }
});
```